# responsive blocks besides main div

Tags: css

I have a main DIV `{width:100%; max-width: 900px}` over body.

I need to place one more DIV exactly over the left free space and another over the right space. May it be done without Javascript and how?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide enough code to re-create your problem - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: Also with the styles you have shown, that div would be left aligned so there would be no space on the left

Comment: yes, {MARGIN:0 AUTO} for main div

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex to achieve what you want:

```css
.container {
  display:flex;           /* make container flex */
  flex-direction:row;     /* line up children in a row */
  width:100%;
}
.center {             /* this is your main div */
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 900px;  

  height: 200px;      /* test value only */
  background:green;
}

.col {
  flex-grow:1;        /* make side columns grow to fill any remaining space */
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="center"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```